# 301 Redirect is not working as expected

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress

Trying to set 301 redirect in `.htaccess` file and here is what i am trying to do

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://localhost/wordpress/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/wordpress/$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am testing this on my local machine using WAMPP server.Though when i hit `http://localhost/wordpress/` i am getting redirected to `http://www.mysite.com/wordpress/` but for other URL i am not getting redirected at all.for e.g

I have this URL in my local machine `http://localhost/wordpress/2010/11/shadows/` and this at the server `http://www.mysite.com/wordpress/2010/11/shadows/` but when i hit this URL i am not getting redirected to respected URL on the live server ,but i am being showed same page from local machine.

**Working**:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/
=> Redirected to:
http://www.mysite.com/wordpress/
```

**Not working**

```
http://localhost/wordpress/2010/11/shadows/
=> Redirected to:
http://www.mysite.com/wordpress/2010/11/shadows/
```

As clear from URL, I am trying to do this in Wordpress.
Here is complete `.htaccess` file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://localhost/wordpress/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/wordpress/$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Can any one tell me whats wrong with the redirection entry? Thanks in advance

**Update**
I have even tried this option

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/wordpress/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Did not worked.

Comment: Please could you type the URL origin, and what the URL redirection should be, and precise if it works or not and I'd be glad to help you

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by URL origin and URL redirection.Sorry being new to this rewrite field

Comment: Something like "Client types `http://localhost/wordpress/` and should be redirected to `http://www.mysite.com/wordpress/` => **works**". Then "Client types `http://localhost/wordpress/2010/11/shadows/` and should be redirected to `http://www.mysite.com/wordpress/2010/11/shadows/` => **doesn't work**" ... and so on. Just to have "clear samples". Thank you =)

Comment: Is that the whole of your `.htaccess`, and if not, can you post the rest? I thought that `%{HTTP_HOST}` was just the contents of the `Host` header, and thus would only be "`localhost`" in your example.

Comment: @nickgrim: i posted the complete htaccess file

Comment: Why would you want to redirect localhost to a webserver? Just replace the 2 rewrite conditions with this line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$`

Comment: @Gerben: i have to do this in the final step,that is from old domain to new domain so just was testing it on my machine

Comment: @Gerben: even what you have suggested is not working

Comment: You need to put the rules above the WP rules, not beneath (regardless of which solution you use). Also use 302 while testing, and clear your browser-cache to remove any old 301's that are being cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Always you first then the others** (talking about RewriteRules *only*, man! :D  ) (and you've forgotten the `QSA` directive).

So here's the "clean" version of your RewriteRule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # BEGIN My Own rewrite rules
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://localhost/wordpress/$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/wordpress/$
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/wordpress/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
  # END My Own rewrite rules

  # BEGIN WordPress
  RewriteBase /wordpress/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
  # END WordPress

</IfModule>
```

---

If it's in a `.htaccess` file then try without the `/` like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # BEGIN My Own rewrite rules
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://localhost/wordpress/$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/wordpress/$
  # Without the / after wordpress:
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/wordpress$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
  # END My Own rewrite rules

  # BEGIN WordPress
  RewriteBase /wordpress/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
  # END WordPress

</IfModule>
```

---

By the way this is the first time in many years that a find an "under construction" page nice!

---

Please tell me if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs and for landing page comments.I checked the above code last night (putting in the first place my redirection) and it was working fine)

Answer (score 0):

`%{HTTP_HOST]` will contain something like `localhost` or `www.thecolorsofmysoul.com`.  So your conditions will never match.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://localhost/wordpress/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/wordpress/$
```

and the redirecting to the external domain will never fire.

Also the first two rule act in consort to map any non-file/directory to `index.php`.  `http://localhost/wordpress/` has a regexp match string of "" so will fail the pattern "`.`" and will fail through and will redirect with your "update".  Try

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /wordpress/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =localhost
RewriteRule ^.*   http://www.thecolorsofmysoul.com/wordpress/$0 [L,R=301]
```

BTW with this base this should be in `DOCROOT/.htaccess`.  The corresponding Wordpress rules (which shouldn't be above this redirect) are

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php$)    index.php   [L]
```

You don't need to repeat the base in the target and the negative lookahead assertion removes the need for the first index.php rule.